# Integral involving Truncated Normal distribution

Tags: integration, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution $Normal(\mu, \sigma)$. Take the following integral:

$$
\int_X (a - X) 1 \{a > X \} dF(X).
$$

where $a$ is a constant value, and $1$ is the indicator function. I encountered this problem while reading a paper, and in that paper the authors claim that this simply the expectation of a truncated normal random variable, and they derive the following expression:

$$
(a - \mu) \Phi (\frac{a - \mu}{\sigma}) + \sigma \phi(\frac{a - \mu}{\sigma}),
$$

where $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are the CDF and PDF of a standard Normal. However, I have no idea how they got to this expression. The expected value of a truncated Normal, according to wikipedia is:

$$
E[X | X < a] = \mu - \sigma \frac{\phi (\frac{a - \mu}{\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{a - \mu}{\sigma})}.
$$

Therefore, the above integral should evaluate to:

$$
E[a-X | X < a] = a - \mu + \sigma \frac{\phi (\frac{a - \mu}{\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{a - \mu}{\sigma})}.
$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: $\int_X (a - X) 1 \{a > X \} dF(X)=E[a-X | X < a] P(X<a)$.

Comment: Just plug in some values for the parameters and show through random sampling that the authors can't be correct.  A reference for that paper would be handy.

Comment: @geetha290krm, how did you get to that expression? I am getting at most $$\int_X (a-X)1\{a>X\}dF(X) = aP(X<a) - E[X | X<a]$$.

Comment: **Definition**: $E(Z|E)=E(Z1_E) P(E)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, thanks, by definition it makes sense. But what is confusing me is why is it the case that $\int_X X1\{X<a\}dF(X) \neq E[X|X<a]$?